# Cypress - writeFile append text and read the last line

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm really struggling on something that maybe someone could help me, I have been trying to write some text information to a file, and append to create something like a list using the code above:

```
const texts = [];
 cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .title').each(($el, index, $list) => {
    texts.push($el.text());
    }).then(() => {
    cy.writeFile('upload.txt', texts.join('\n'), { flag: 'a+' });
 })
```

But so far I have some issues, the value of the field I was trying to get is something similar to:

> Cypress-Upload- 203371

But this is was the first result:

> Cypress-Upload- 203371Cypress-Upload- 585335Cypress-Upload- 678195Cypress-Upload- 414595

I need to write one result per line, and read the last file, to read I'm using:

```
cy.readFile('upload.txt')
  .then((text) => {
cy.get('input[id="search-input"]')
  .type(text)
```

But the field is filling with the breakline and space, I need to strip anything and use just the text from the line.

Any help will be appreciated, I'm not experienced on cypress, just starting to learn and write first tests now and loving so far, so any tip will be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with a friend's help.

What we did was just map, trim and filter the value before use:

```
var fileLines = textLines.split("\n").map(val => (val || '').trim()).filter(val => !!val)
const lastText = fileLines.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.each()` to iterate can sometimes be problematic. I would use `.then()` with an array map instead

```js
cy.get('.title').then($titles => {

  const titleTexts = [...$titles].map($title => $title.textContent); // map to texts

  cy.writeFile('upload.txt', titleTexts.join("\n"));    // no need for {flag: 'a+'}
})

cy.readFile('upload.txt').then(textLines => {

  const lastText = textLines.split("\n").pop() 

  cy.get('input#search-input')  // "#" is shorter selector for id 
    .type(lastText)
    .invoke('val')                
    .should('eq', 'three')      // check it has the value
})
```

This is the HTML I tested on

```
<div>
  <div class="title">one</div> 
  <div class="title">two</div> 
  <div class="title">three</div> 

  <input id="search-input" />

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, but still the same results. the files are not appending anymore are just writing only the last result. 

``` Cypress-Upload- 414596 ``` The result above is what I'm seeing in the file, look at the space on the first and last line. And the search input is typing only space and found nothing.

Comment: That's not what I get, you must be applying it incorrectly. You will have to post the DOM you are working with.